Can null_resource Execute Scripts on Local Machine Instead of Terraform Cloud?
I’m currently working with Terraform Cloud to create an Azure Container App using Terraform as part of my Infrastructure as Code (IaC) efforts. I’m using a null_resource with the local-exec provisioner to execute a script that builds a Docker image and pushes it to Azure Container Registry (ACR). However, I've run into a limitation where the script doesn’t execute as intended because Terraform Cloud runs in a remote environment.
Here’s a snippet of my configuration (sample):
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "myUniqueACRName"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Basic"
  admin_enabled       = true
}

resource "null_resource" "deploy_image_acr" {
  triggers = {
    deploy_time = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./deploy_to_acr.sh ${var.client_id} ${var.client_secret} ${var.tenant_id} ${var.subscription_id} ${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name} ${var.image_name}"
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_container_registry.acr]
}

Bash Script:
#!/bin/bash

# Login to Azure with the Service Principal
az login --service-principal -u "$1" -p="$2" --tenant "$3"

# Set the desired subscription
az account set --subscription "$4"

# Remove all existing images
for repo in $(az acr repository list --name "$5" --output tsv); do
  az acr repository delete --name "$5" --repository "$repo" --yes
done

# Build and push the new image

docker build -t <image_name> .. 

az acr login --name $5

docker tag <image_name> $5.azurecr.io/<image_name>

docker push $5.azurecr.io/<image_name>

The Problem:
When I try to apply this configuration in Terraform Cloud, the local-exec provisioner does not execute the script because it's designed to run on the local machine where Terraform is executed.
Questions:

Is there a way to execute scripts that are defined in a null_resource or any other resource on my local machine while using Terraform Cloud?
If local execution isn’t possible, what alternative approaches can I use to run Docker commands or scripts as part of my deployment workflow?


All resources are applied from the TFCloud agent, and in this case that would include the null_resource. You probably want to configure a custom agent for your Terraform applications in TFCloud that supports your command. It is also unclear what that script is doing as it is not shared in the question, but there is probably a plugin provider that supports its functionality as well, and then that would also fix your issue.

@MatthewSchuchard, could you please take a look? I have added the Bash script.

Don't try to over-extend Terraform. Let it provision infrastructure; that's what it's designed to do and that's what it's good at. Let other, more appropriate tooling handle everything else.

To execute scripts defined in a null_resource or any other resource on my local machine while using Terraform Cloud:
Solution: Ensure that your execution mode is set to local in your workspace. This will store the state file inside Terraform while all infrastructure provisioning occurs on your local machine.
Terraform File Example:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "4.2.0"
    }
  }
  
  cloud {
    organization = "org-name"
    
    workspaces {
      name = "wk-space"
    }
  }
}

Setting to Look For in Terraform Cloud:
Navigate to Workspace Settings > Execution Mode.

Documentation: Terraform Cloud Execution Mode

Here is the updated Terraform configuration and CLI script to pull and push the image to ACR.

Note: Make sure to place both the .tf and .ps1 files in the same directory.

Main.tf
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = ""
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                     = "venaktacrtesting"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                      = "Premium"
  admin_enabled            = true
}

resource "null_resource" "Powershell_script1" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ${path.module}/ACR.ps1 -ACRName "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.name}" -ACRLoginServer "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}" -ACRUsername "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_username}" -ACRPassword "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.admin_password}"
    EOT
  }
  depends_on = [azurerm_container_registry.acr]
}


The below CLI commands will download, tag, and push the images to the specified ACR repository
ACR.ps1
param (
    [string]$ACRName,
    [string]$ACRLoginServer,
    [string]$ACRUsername,
    [string]$ACRPassword
)

az acr login --name $ACRName --username $ACRUsername --password $ACRPassword
$repolist = az acr repository list -n $ACRLoginServer
foreach ($repolists in $repolist) {
    az acr repository delete -n $ACRLoginServer --repository $repolists --yes
}
docker pull nginx
docker tag nginx $ACRLoginServer/sampleimage/nginx:v1
docker push $ACRLoginServer/sampleimage/nginx:v1

Terraform apply

After running the Terraform script, the images are downloaded locally, tagged with a different name, and then pushed to the ACR.



I hope this helps to resolve your issue.
